# How do I remove the default underlines in my html code?

Tags: html

I have created a container which has a picture inside and some text. However every time I open up the html the text inside the container appears as a link or underlined. How can I remove the default underline/link using html or CSS?

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Use the css property text-decoration: none; in the container

Answer (score 0):

so simple to remove under line you have to use `css`

```
text-decoration:none;
```

this rule will remove under line

add this to your css and try

```
a{
   text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

if you still see underline post your html code